# Arithmetic/logic operations with large sparse tensors in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, tensor

I need to make quick calculations (+,*,>) with large 3D arrays (tensors) in R (like 1500 x 150 x 30000). Since these arrays are very sparse (only 0.03% entries are non-zeros) I first use as_sptensor function from the 'tensorr' library to convert my tensors to sparse ones like:

x <- array(data = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1) , dim = c(3,2,2))

s <- as_dtensor(x)

s1 <- as_sptensor(s)

And then I do some arithmetic operations, e.g. multiplication:

s1*s1

I also have memory limitations of 8GB totally so that also help s me to store the result.

The problem is that when I deal with large tensors like:

A <-some_index_matrix[1:3,1:1000000]

A2 <- sptensor(A, rep(1,ncol(A)), dims=c(max(A[1,]),max(A[2,]),max(A[3,])))

A2*A2

I fail to get this product result within reasonable time. How can I optimize my code for such calculations to be carried out within seconds?